# Use array/list/sequence for repetitive code?

Tags: programming

For a PhD thesis cover template in our university, there is some code as follow:

```
%%% Jury member n1 (Président) %%%
\newcommand{\jurynameA}{M. Cabot}
\newcommand{\juryadressA}{Someplace}
\newcommand{\jurygradeA}{Somerank}
\newcommand{\juryroleA}{Président du jury}
%%% Jury member n2 (Rapporteur) %%%
\newcommand{\jurynameB}{M. Blonde}
\newcommand{\juryadressB}{Anotherplace}
\newcommand{\jurygradeB}{Anotherrank}
\newcommand{\juryroleB}{Rapporteur} % 
%%% Jury member n3 (Rapporteur) %%%
\newcommand{\jurynameC}{M. Blue}
\newcommand{\juryadressC}{Someotherplace}
\newcommand{\jurygradeC}{Someotherrank}
\newcommand{\juryroleC}{Rapporteur}
%%% Jury member n4 (Examinateur) %%%
\newcommand{\jurynameD}{M. Brown}
\newcommand{\juryadressD}{Yetanotherplace}
\newcommand{\jurygradeD}{Yetanotherrank}
\newcommand{\juryroleD}{Examinateur}
%%% Jury member n5 (Examinateur) %%%
\newcommand{\jurynameE}{M. Orange}
\newcommand{\juryadressE}{Onemoreplace}
\newcommand{\jurygradeE}{One more rank}
\newcommand{\juryroleE}{Examinateur}
%%% Jury member n6 (Directeur) %%%
\newcommand{\jurynameF}{M. Pink}
\newcommand{\juryadressF}{Yourplace}
\newcommand{\jurygradeF}{HDR}
\newcommand{\juryroleF}{Directeur de thèse}
%%% Jury member n7 (Co-Directeur) %%%
\newcommand{\jurynameG}{M. White}
\newcommand{\juryadressG}{Yourotherplace}
\newcommand{\jurygradeG}{HDR?}
\newcommand{\juryroleG}{Co-Directeur de thèse}
\begin{tabular}{lll}

    \textsc{\jurynameA}  & \jurygradeA & (\juryroleA) \\
    \null  & \textit{\juryadressA} & \\

    \textsc{\jurynameB}  & \jurygradeB & (\juryroleB) \\
    \null  & \textit{\juryadressB} & \\

    \textsc{\jurynameC}  & \jurygradeC & (\juryroleC) \\
    \null  & \textit{\juryadressC} & \\

    \textsc{\jurynameD}  & \jurygradeD & (\juryroleD) \\
    \null  & \textit{\juryadressD} & \\

    \textsc{\jurynameE}  & \jurygradeE & (\juryroleE) \\
    \null  & \textit{\juryadressE} & \\

    \textsc{\jurynameF}  & \jurygradeF & (\juryroleF) \\
    \null  & \textit{\juryadressF} & \\

    \textsc{\jurynameG}  & \jurygradeG & (\juryroleG) \\
    \null  & \textit{\juryadressG} & \\

\end{tabular}
```

I was wondering if it would be possible to input data more easily (something like `\addmember{M. Pink}{Yourplace}{HDR}{Directeur de thèse}`), and then have the table generated automatically without worrying about the number of jury members (some people may have 4 members, some up to 8).

In Python for instance, I would have used a list of dict (or just of lists if I did not care about semantics), each dict describing a jury member, and would have iterated over that list to write the table. Is it possible to do something like that with LaTeX?

Comment: `pgfplotstable` allows you to typeset a table from a dataset you load.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way to do it using standard LaTeX methods from `etoolbox` and `pgffor`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor,etoolbox,array}
\newcounter{members}
\newcommand{\addmember}[4]{%
\ifnum\value{members}=8
    \typeout{Warning: your committee has too many members! Extra members ignored.}
\else
    \stepcounter{members}
    \csgdef{juryname\themembers}{#1}
    \csgdef{juryadress\themembers}{#2}
    \csgdef{jurygrade\themembers}{#3}
    \csgdef{juryrole\themembers}{#4}
\fi
}
\newcommand{\thecommitee}{}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\makecommittee}{%
\foreach \x in {1,...,\value{members}}{
\protected@xappto{\thecommittee}{%
\csuse{juryname\x} &
\csuse{jurygrade\x} &
(\csuse{juryrole\x})\tabularnewline
&\itshape\csuse{juryadress\x} &\tabularnewline
}
}
\begin{tabular}{>{\scshape}lll}
\thecommittee
\end{tabular}
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\addmember{M. Cabot}{Montréal}{PhD}{Président du jury}
\addmember{M. Blonde}{Trois Rivières}{PhD}{Rapporteur}
\addmember{M. Brun}{Québec}{PhD}{Examinateur}
\addmember{M. Vert}{Paris}{PhD}{Examinateur}
\addmember{M. Gris}{Montréal}{PhD}{Directeur de thèse}
\makecommittee
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]